# Sinch - App to Phone Cordova - Crosswalk iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, sinch, crosswalk

Is there a way to run the Sinch Voice js sdk version on iOS using cordova and crosswalk?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

No, not the JS SDK to work with Cordova you could build a plugin on the Native SDKS but not on the JS SDK. Why? There is no WebRTC in the webviews so you will have to use the Native SDKs to get WebRTC in to the app.

Comment: Hi @cjensen , is Sinch going to make Cordova Plugin for iOS version?
We're planning to use cordova so we can release in Web App and Mobile Apps faster. Thank you

Comment: No at the moment, There a guy at Kwingle that did a Xamarin plugin if that is an option for cross plattform. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/174520/#Comment_174520

Comment: we just move out from xamarin and now go with cordova.
could you please check this plugin https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc  . Can it work with sinch? Thanks christian.